# Javascript files not loading in rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I do not know what happened but suddenly javascript files stopped to load
for me. :)

This is how my layout file looks like:

```
<head>
  <title> Bookshelf16thMar </title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Currently, it only loads "application.js". I thought it should load every js file available in app/assets/javascripts/. Please let me know what extra information you need to help it resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the content of application.js?

Comment: When you said "javascript files stopped to load for me", did you mean *it was working fine before*?

Comment: @Benjamin.. Thanks man. Unintentionally, I deleted the lines from application.js. Restore it again and it worked. Cool.

Comment: @TaoP.R. Thanks for your prompt reply. Benjamin already resolved it for me.